# What is the single dot and double dots in the return value of function readdir() in php

Tags: php, readdir, opendir

I've been confused with the concept which descriped in php.net for the function is_dir(),it says

> Tells whether the given filename is a directory

(1)It checks whether the given parameter is a directory or not,when I give it a path,it returns true on success,but it uses the term **given filename**,if I know it is filename(file returns false),why would I bothering checking it in the first place?

(2)Here comes the spot where I've been confused of,readdir returns the files resides inside the given folder,it returns the file names but also returns single dot and double dots while I looping the opendir(),so,what exactly does the dots means in the return value?

Answer (score 3):

Its very simple i think.
The singe dot represents the current directory and the double dot the parent directory.
In the root directory there would be no double dot.
 If you use the "ls -a" Linux command there will be the same output (single and double dot). 
This is very useful in some cases to be able to see which permissions are given in the parent or the current directory.
I don't know it for sure, but i think the readdir function uses the same interface which causes the dots. (maybe php simply uses the "ls" statement internally or something like that)

you could simply skip this two "files" in a loop with something like:

```
if ($file == "." or $file == "..") continue;
```

Comment: but when I put the test file in the path three levels down the root directory,it also contains one single dot and one double dots,is it surposed to have at least three dots?

Comment: the dot syntax is relatively to the current directory. if you show the content of an directory there is always a single dot and a double dot. there like links into the current and the parent directory. there are always tree dots in total. every folder has a parent folder so there have to be a double dot. if you want to access a executable in a directory in Linux you cant simply type the file name into the terminal because the system looks for the file in the environment path but not the current folder. the trick is to write "./exec". now Linux knows about the relation to the current directory.